# ogr2ogr transform failure: "illegal axis orientation combination"

Tags: ogr2ogr

I'm attempting to use ogr2ogr to reproject a MA community boundaries shapefile (available [here](http://www.mass.gov/anf/research-and-tech/it-serv-and-support/application-serv/office-of-geographic-information-massgis/datalayers/townsurvey.html)).  Question: what part of the command causes the transformation fail? Is either my code or the source projection invalid?

Let's call the `TOWNSSURVEY_POLY.shp` shapefile `src.shp` for convenience. My command,

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -t_srs EPSG:4326 dest.json src.shp
```

yields the following error for which which I cannot find any documentation:

```
ERROR 1: illegal axis orientation combination
ERROR 1: Failed to reproject feature 0 (geometry probably out of source or destination SRS).
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
```

src.shp has the following projection:

```
PROJ.4 : '+proj=lcc +lat_1=41.71666666666667 +lat_2=42.68333333333333 +lat_0=41 +lon_0=-71.5 +x_0=200000 +y_0=750000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["Lambert_Conformal_Conic",
    GEOGCS["GCS_GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",41.71666666666667],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",42.68333333333333],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",41],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-71.5],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",200000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",750000],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

While dest.json is created, it contains no features.

Edit: yep, I meant EPSG:4326, and have changed it in the code above. The error remains despite the fix.  `cat dest.json` yields an empty string.  `gdal-config --version` yields `2.1.0` (I use the anaconda gdal dist). I will attempt to (re)compile gdal 2.1.2 from source tomorrow, as it is the most recent stable source release.
 I've edited in the exact shapefile name as well.
Final edit: completely forgot about this.  Iirc, the coordinates were flipped.

Comment: Without the GeoJson, we can do nothing

Comment: Do you really mean EPSG:4236?

Comment: It's probably supposed to be 4326 (WGS84) or 4269 (NAD83).

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with GDAL 2.2dev version. No error with command `ogr2ogr -f geojson -t_srs epsg:4326 poly.json townssurvey_poly.shp` and using t_srs epsg:4236 works as well. Please tell exactly what dataset you used so we do not need to guess.